# Change the background of my webpage with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a **very** long time I have been wondering how to change my background-image on a webpage I code, but when the user refreshes my website I want their changes to still be there. Like they change the background with a click, and when they refreshes the page I want that background to still be there for them. Do I have to use local storage or cookies? In that case can someone teach me how?

Thank you for taking your time to read this and I hope I get a good answer.

An example of my code: http://koda.nu/arkivet/33733671 (password: "cwm", open in fullscreen). And I do have tried to learn localStorage.

Comment: First of all, please do some efforts, show us some code so that people can help you further. 
Study about web storage, cookies and database. Your question just depends on requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var body = document.body;

// Apply if present in storage
if (localStorage.bgcolor) body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgcolor;

// Set on button click
document.querySelectorAll("[data-bgcolor]").forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.bgcolor = this.getAttribute("data-bgcolor");
  })
);
```

```html
<button data-bgcolor="red">red</button>
<button data-bgcolor="#00f">blue</button>
<button data-bgcolor="white">white</button>
```